# vb.net: how to count row of searched value from one column

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, count

lets say there are two columns
date received and item

if i searched a date where there are 5 rows of the same date

it will appear in textbox

i nid help plss

*note , i use oledb as database connection

this is my search code

```
Private Sub TxSearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxSearch.TextChanged


    If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Con.Open()
    End If

    Dad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select RecordDate, Item from inv where RecordDate LIKE '%" & TxSearch.Text & "%'", Con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dad.Fill(dt)

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    Con.Close()
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
    DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    Con.Close()


    SortDatagridviewColumn(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private Sub TxSearch_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TxSearch.TextChanged

```
If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    Con.Open()
End If

Dad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select RecordDate, Item from inv where RecordDate LIKE '%" & TxSearch.Text & "%'", Con)
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dad.Fill(dt)

Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

    Dim counter As String
    counter = dt.Rows.Count.ToString
    textBoxRowCount.Text = counter


Con.Close()
DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue
DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
Con.Close()


SortDatagridviewColumn(0)


Private Sub textBoxRowCount_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles textBoxRowCount.TextChanged

End Sub
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Could be just this:

```
....
Dad.Fill(dt)
textBoxRowCount.Text = "Found " + dt.Rows.Count + " rows"
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
....
```

EDIT: Change your query to use parameters, do not ever try to concatenate strings to build sql commands

```
Dim sqlText = "select RecordDate, Item from inv where RecordDate LIKE @search"
Dad = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlText, Con)
Dad.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + TextSearch.Text + "%")
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dad.Fill(dt)
```

However in the case above RecordDate is considered as it is a Text field, if, instead, RecordDate is a database field of DateTime type there is no sense to use LIKE. You should use equal (=) or the sql clause `BETWEEN`

Looking at your comment then you could write a query to count records, (the considerations on RecordDate are still valid)

```
Dim sqlText = "select COUNT(*) from inv where RecordDate LIKE @search"
Dim cmd  = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlText, Con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + TextSearch.Text + "%")
Dim resultCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: What's your problem? You don't know how to count the rows retrieved or you don't retrieve any row at all?

Comment: no, not like that

i just want to count the item base on the date searched

for example if i have 5 items received from 03/18/2013

then count on the next textbox will appear as 5

if i searched for the item received of 03/20/2013 w/c is 6
then count box will view 6

Comment: is it possible you want your sql to return the COUNT of rows meeting a certain criteria?

Comment: i have no problem with searching, i nid the count of item base on date
if i typed the date on the 1st textbox, then the datagridview will view 5 rows, and 2nd textbox will also reveal number 5


it was for the purpose if i already completed the logic successfully, then i will use it instead for if else staement to disable button if amount of this is equal to